# Remove a string from wordpress URL

Tags: wordpress

Upon publishing a post through the nice WordPress plugin "Press-this extended" redirects to the published post appending a string on the url which all other posts do not have. The url is as follows: mysite.com/?post_type=post&p=xxxx as opposed to the regular ones which have just: mysite.com/?p=xxxx

What is wanted is simply the omission of the "post_type=post&" string from the urls that have it, which are only the urls generated by this plugin. Using the classic editor does not add this string.
What's the simplest way of achieving this? By a function? By htaccess?
I searched and tried similar questions and solutions but could not resolve it.
Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: how you want to show now?

Comment: Hello @Arman, thank you for your interest. I want it from "mysite.com/?post_type=post&p=xxxx" to "mysite.com/?p=xxxx" Simply taking out the "post_type=post" parameter or query string from the url.